# What tradeoffs are there between internal and external validity?

Tags: methodology, experimental-psychology

I was reading through an [article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2912019/#b1-0530278) about research design. The authors gave an example on the relation between internal and external validity which I thought might be an important area of consideration when designing research proposals.

> "A restricted study population (and exclusion criteria) may limit bias
>   and increase the internal validity of the study; however, this
>   approach will limit external validity of the study and, thus, the
>   generalizability of the findings to the practical clinical setting.
>   Conversely, a broadly defined study population and inclusion criteria
>   may be representative of practical clinical practice but may increase
>   bias and reduce the internal validity of the study."

Broadly speaking, what questions can be asked to help decide one should strike a balance between the internal and external validity in our research proposal designs? Is it necessary then to carry out a pilot study first to establish some level of internal validity before moving on to establish external validity in a much bigger and formal follow-up study?

Crosspost: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Validity/What-tradeoffs-are-there-between-internal-and-external-validity)

Update: This post has been shifted to [academia.stackexchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/59212/what-tradeoffs-are-there-between-internal-and-external-validity). All changes and edits will be made via the posting there henceforth.

Comment: What does this have to do with cognitive science? Wouldn't http://academia.stackexchange.com/ be a much better place to ask this?

Comment: Izhaki, thanks for the heads-up, will shift the post to academia.stackexchange.

Comment: For anyone tracking, it ended up [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185609/what-tradeoffs-are-there-between-internal-and-external-validity)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the was cross-posted (and has answers) at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185609/what-tradeoffs-are-there-between-internal-and-external-validity